# material icons not importing in vue

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs2, google-material-icons

I have following icons npm package installed.

```
"material-icons": "^0.3.1"
```

I have imported them as following.

```
<style lang="sass">
$material-icons-font-path: '~material-icons/iconfont/';
@import '~material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.scss';
</style>
```

and I am using their classes as following.

```
<i class="rotate_right"></i>
```

But icons are not showing up. I have created vue application using vue cli 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-icons), you should use span with content is icon's name. Please try

```
<span class="material-icons">rotate_right</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a typo in your import statement...

```
@import '~material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.scss'; whereas it should be @import '~material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
```

For me, giving the path as `@import '../../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';` worked !